# Designing linear layout

Tags: imageview, android-linearlayout, textview, android

I am trying to design a layout which is containing 2 textView at the rightside of imageView.

I know that it is easy to design it with Relative layout.

But i want to design it using linear layout.

Please provide some hints or code to do this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You can use `LinearLayouts` in nested way, one inside the other and so on.

Refer to the following image from [Developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)

[image]

From the image it is clear that for your case you need to create a linear layout inside that create a imageView and a LinearLayout(called linearLayout2). Now Inside linearLayout2 create two textViews.

Answer (score 0):

Visualize the Linear layout with orientation set to horizontal and set layout_weight to each control. A layout weight of 0.5 means a control will take up the left half of the linear layout (50%).